# Extracting particular text from html file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a code like given below. I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape text in class = 'product'. But I wanted only 2nd and 4th value(ie. 'Product 2' and 'Product 4') in my extracted csv file. As of now I only know to extract all the values(ie. 'Product 1' 'Product 2' 'Product 3' 'Product 4').

```html
<body>
    <div class="product">Product 1</div>
    <div class="product">Product 2</div>
    <div class="product">Product 3</div>
    <div class="product">Product 4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is that code said to be below? I can only see a very simple html page

Answer (score 2):

[`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns a list, so use indexes to get the desired elements

```
result = data_soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "product"})
print(result[1], result[3])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.